# Assigning numbers to contenders based on odds

Tags: python, pandas

I want to assign number 1, 2 or 3 based on the odds as shown below. So that, favorite in Place A at Time 13:30 which is Contender L will have a number 1 who has the highest probability (lowest odds) to win, M will have a number 2 and so on. I am using `pandas` in `python`. I used several `groupby` functions but wasn't successful. Will appreciate any help at this point.

```
| Place        |  Time         | Contender      | Odds       |
| :----------- | :------------ | :------------- | :--------- |
|     A        |       13:30   | L              | 2.5        |
|     A        |       13:30   | M              | 4.5        |
|     A        |       13:30   | N              | 5.5        |
|     B        |       13:40   | X              | 1.5        |
|     B        |       13:40   | Y              | 3.5        |
|     B        |       13:40   | Z              | 6.5        |
|     D        |       13:50   | T              | 5.5        |
|     D        |       13:50   | S              | 6.5        |
|     D        |       13:50   | P              | 1.5        |
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need [`GroupBy.rank`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.rank.html) with `min` or `dense` parameter, difference is:

> **method** : {'average', 'min', 'max', 'first', 'dense'}, default 'average'
>
> **min**: lowest rank in group
>   **dense**: like ‘min’, but rank always increases by 1 between groups

```
df['new1'] = df.groupby(['Place','Time'])['Odds'].rank('min').astype(int)
df['new2'] = df.groupby(['Place','Time'])['Odds'].rank('dense').astype(int)
print (df)
  Place   Time Contender  Odds  new1  new2
0     A  13:30         L   2.5     1     1
1     A  13:30         M   4.5     3     2
2     A  13:30         N   2.5     1     1 <-changed 5.5 to 2.5 for see difference
3     B  13:40         X   1.5     1     1
4     B  13:40         Y   3.5     2     2
5     B  13:40         Z   6.5     3     3
6     D  13:50         T   5.5     2     2
7     D  13:50         S   6.5     3     3
8     D  13:50         P   1.5     1     1
```